# Efficient conversion of dataframe distinct values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data like this:

```
republican,n,y,n,y,y,y,n,n,n,y,?,y,y,y,n,y
republican,n,y,n,y,y,y,n,n,n,n,n,y,y,y,n,?
democrat,?,y,y,?,y,y,n,n,n,n,y,n,y,y,n,n
democrat,n,y,y,n,?,y,n,n,n,n,y,n,y,n,n,y
democrat,y,y,y,n,y,y,n,n,n,n,y,?,y,y,y,y
democrat,n,y,y,n,y,y,n,n,n,n,n,n,y,y,y,y
democrat,n,y,n,y,y,y,n,n,n,n,n,n,?,y,y,y
republican,n,y,n,y,y,y,n,n,n,n,n,n,y,y,?,y
```

from [source](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/voting-records/house-votes-84.data).
I would like to change all different distinct values from all of the data (`dataframe`) into numeric values in most efficient way. 
In the above mentioned example I would like to transform republican-> 1 and democrat -> 2, y ->3, n->4 and ? -> 5 (or NULL).

I tried to use the following:

```
# Convert string column to integer
def str_column_to_int(dataset, column):
    class_values = [row[column] for row in dataset]
    unique = set(class_values)
    lookup = dict()
    for i, value in enumerate(unique):
        lookup[value] = i
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = lookup[row[column]]
    return lookup
```

However, I'm not sure if using `Pandas` can be more efficient or there are some other better solutions for it. (This should be generic to any source of data).
Here is the transform of data into `dataframe` using `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/voting-records/house-votes-84.data'
dataset = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v = df.values

f = pd.factorize(v.ravel())[0].reshape(v.shape)

pd.DataFrame(f)

   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0   0   1   2   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   2   3   2   2   2   1   2
1   0   1   2   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   1   3
2   4   3   2   2   3   2   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   1   1
3   4   1   2   2   1   3   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
4   4   2   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   2   3   2   2   2   2
5   4   1   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2
6   4   1   2   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   2   2   2
7   0   1   2   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   3   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace` on the whole dataframe to make the mappings. You could first pass a dictionary of known mappings for values you need to remain consistent, and then generate a set of values for the dataset and map these extra values to say values `100` upwards.

For example, the `?` here is not mapped, so would get a value of `100`:

```
mappings = {'republican':1, 'democrat':2, 'y':3, 'n':4}
unknown = set(pd.unique(df.values.ravel())) - set(mappings.keys())
mappings.update([v, c] for c, v in enumerate(unknown, start=100))
df.replace(mappings, inplace=True)
```

Giving you:

```
   republican    n  n.1  n.2  n.3  n.4  n.5  n.6  n.7  n.8  n.9    ?  n.10  n.11  n.12  n.13  n.14
0           1    4    3    4    3    3    3    4    4    4    3  100     3     3     3     4     3
1           1    4    3    4    3    3    3    4    4    4    4    4     3     3     3     4   100
2           2  100    3    3  100    3    3    4    4    4    4    3     4     3     3     4     4
3           2    4    3    3    4  100    3    4    4    4    4    3     4     3     4     4     3
4           2    3    3    3    4    3    3    4    4    4    4    3   100     3     3     3     3
5           2    4    3    3    4    3    3    4    4    4    4    4     4     3     3     3     3
6           2    4    3    4    3    3    3    4    4    4    4    4     4   100     3     3     3
7           1    4    3    4    3    3    3    4    4    4    4    4     4     3     3   100     3
```

A more generalized version would be:

```
mappings = {v:c for c, v in enumerate(sorted(set(pd.unique(df.values.ravel()))), start=1)}
df.replace(mappings, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin Evans, Can you please generalize your solution so that there won't be a need for hard coding the values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
v = df.values

a, b = v.shape
f = pd.factorize(v.T.ravel())[0].reshape(b,a).T

df = pd.DataFrame(f)
print (df)
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0   0   2   4   2   4   4   4   2   2   2   4   3   4   4   4   2   4
1   0   2   4   2   4   4   4   2   2   2   2   2   4   4   4   2   3
2   1   3   4   4   3   4   4   2   2   2   2   4   2   4   4   2   2
3   1   2   4   4   2   3   4   2   2   2   2   4   2   4   2   2   4
4   1   4   4   4   2   4   4   2   2   2   2   4   3   4   4   4   4
5   1   2   4   4   2   4   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   4   4   4   4
6   1   2   4   2   4   4   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   4   4   4
7   0   2   4   2   4   4   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   4   4   3   4
```